# What is the error in the if statement to determine the sort of a pivot field?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

```
If wb.ws("Table").PivotTables("1").PivotFields("Date").AutoSort = xlAscending 
Then
     MsgBox "Ascending"
End if
```

I receive a wrong number of arguments error when this is run code.
My goal is to determine if the field is sorted ascending.
What is my error?

Answer (score 0):

`PivotTables` accepts integer as an argument. So, your call should be `PivotTable(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`AutoSort` is a method that applies sorting, it is not a property. You need:

```
If wb.ws("Table").PivotTables("1").PivotFields("Date").AutoSortOrder = xlAscending 
Then
     MsgBox "Ascending"
End if
```